# PyLint detect undefined variables that are defined and used in if statement or with ... as statement inside a class definition

Tags: python, if-statement, pylint, with-statement, file-manipulation

I was doing some analysis about the Coronavirus and PyLint detect some undefined variables that are defined in an if statement or by a with statement. my code work as expected and is see no errors or runtime warnings. Here's my code :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,date
import os
import requests
import numpy as np

class Covid:
    filename = 'data/' + str(date.today()) + '.csv'
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        res = requests.get("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv")
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(res.content.decode( "ISO-8859-1"))    
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=',', parse_dates=['dateRep'], date_parser=dateparse, encoding= "ISO-8859-1")
```

the `__init__` and the other functions of the class are after this.

My problem is that PyLint show me warnings about undefined variables:
the `f` at line 12, just after the `as`, where it's defined,
the `f` at line 13,
the `res` at line 13 (this warning disappear if i define `res` outside of the if statement).

It's not a major issue since my program still run but I'd like to understand why does PyLint shows me theses warnings and to get rid of theses warnings.
They don't appear if I do all of this outside the class definition.

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is it PyLint that not do what it is supposed to do ?

I am working with Visual Studio Code,
pylint 2.4.4
astroid 2.3.3
and Python 3.8.2